# The idea behind Sagnac loop for entangled pair generation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, non-linear-optics

I have a question which I cannot intuitively understand. In many articles I saw a Sagnac loop being used to generate polarization entangled pairs of photons. The principle is rather simple - you split the pump beam into two beams with perpendicular polarization, which then propagate through Sagnac loop in two opposite directions generating vertically and horizontally polarized signal and idler waves.
The question is: if entanglement is created by four-wave mixing process then why do you need the Sagnac loop? Is it to randomize the polarization at the output? Do pump photons have to propagate through both arms **simultaneously** or does it propagate through **either** H or V oriented arms?

Comment: The article I read had the loops made with the downconversion material embedded, the interference part may just be tuning so that certain wavelengths only are selected to boost output yield of entangled pairs.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual setup, the entangled photons are generated by downconversion in a single BBO crystal and then directed through colored filters to select for the desired wavelength which is twice that of the original source. All other wavelengths are extraneous.                                                    The Sagnac loop is used for specific experiments but it plays no role in either down conversion or the generation of entangled pairs. The entangled pairs are generated simultaneously in the BOB crystal so they pass through the loops simultaneously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).